# Azure logic app 'Create SAS URI by Path' connector is failing to connect to storage account

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps

I have a logic app where I am creating a blob in a storage account and then I am trying to fetch the URL of that particular file using **'Create SAS URI by Path'**.

[Here is the flow of my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1y4zQ.png)

I have tried both ***Azure AD Connection and Managed identity connection*** ***(for the blog storage connectors. For security reason, I couldn't try the access key method)***.

***Create Blob*** connector works perfectly fine for both the connection but when I try to fetch the URL of the newly created blob using ***Create SAS URI by Path*** , it keeps failing for the below error message:

> { "error": "'Operation not supported with AAD authentication, use
> Azure Storage Account name/key connection instead.' " }

I am using consumption azure plan FYI.

Is there a way this error can be fixed or any another workaround to get the URL of the blob?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to reproduce in my environment, and I got results and followed below work-around:

I have used account key and it worked for me as below:

[image]

In logic app:

[image]

[image]

As your error says use Account Storage key, I have used the same and i didnt get any error in Consumption plan and please try to follow this as it worked for me and is should do the same to you.

Comment: that's the issue I don't have/can't use account key for security reasons